# Библиотека для Python, с помощью которой возможно сделать скриншот из окна, перекрытого другими окнами

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, скриншот

С помощью какой библиотеки под Python возможно делать скриншот из окна, перекрытого другими окнами? Зная хендл необходимого окна или название его заголовка. Pillow не подходит тем, что (на сколько я понял) с ее помощью делается снимок лишь с заданными координатами рабочего стола, но не окна, которое находится на заднем плане и перекрыто вышележащими окнами.

Comment: В общем случае это может оказаться технически невозможно, потому что скрытое окно может оказаться просто не прорисовано (или частично прорисовано, как повезёт) и скриншотить в итоге нечего

Comment: andreymal, знаю что это возможно (по крайней мере в моем случае), потому что эту операцию успешно осуществляет другое ПО, в котором я указываю хендл перекрытого окна и получаю из него скриншот.